# Edit Text size/font using c# Interop for text just added using "oDoc.Content.Text += reportText.Heading"

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

```
        foreach (ReportItem reportItem in reportItems)
        {
            if (reportItem is ReportText reportText)
            {
                oDoc.Content.Text += reportText.Heading;
                oDoc.Content.Text += reportText.Text;
            }

        }
        oDoc.Save();
        oDoc.Close();
        word.Quit();
```

Each reportItem has text and a header. I want the header to be larger than the text and maybe bold. However i dont know how to select that text that has just been entered. Ive tried to select paragraphs but that seems to be erratic and i cant seem to get it right.

Comment: I notice you posted a question a while back that never got an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266211/how-do-i-create-a-table-from-a-datagridview-and-add-to-a-already-present-word-do), probably because it wasn't tagged optimally. Did you solve this? Please note for Microsoft Word you should use the tag MS-WORD (and not just "word" - please see the tag info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to assign to the entire docuemnt's content, use `Range` objects as the data "targets". Each section of text that should be formatted differently needs to be inserted individually (so you can't use `+=` for all the content).

Based on the example in the question, that could look something like this:

```
Word.Range rngTarget = oDoc.Content;
object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
    foreach (ReportItem reportItem in reportItems)
    {
        if (reportItem is ReportText reportText)
        {
            rngTarget.Text = reportText.Heading;
            rngTarget.Font.Size = 12;
            rngTarget.Bold = -1;
            rngTarget.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
            rngTarget.Text += reportText.Text;
            rngTarget.Font.Size = 10;
            rngTarget.Bold = 0;
            rngTarget.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
        }
    }
    oDoc.Save();
    oDoc.Close();
    word.Quit();
```

If you absolutely feel you must use `+=` then you need to include "markers" in the text to indicate the start and end points of "Header" and "Text". After the content has been inserted you'd then need to use Word's `Find` functionality to locate these and apply the formatting.

Comment: thank-you very much. Its exactly what i wanted. I just added in rngTarget.Paragraphs.Add(); 
before 
rngTarget.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd); 
to put the text on a new line.